# Measure timing within a function in r

Tags: r, function

This may be a duplicate question, but I've tried a number of different searches and haven't found a question here or anywhere else.

I'm trying to understand what part of a function is taking the most time.

I remember using a function some months ago that would breakdown the amount of time spent on each expression within a function. I think I found it in a discussion of how to decide when parallel processing was beneficial.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: For a more visually oriented profiler, try [lineprof](https://github.com/hadley/lineprof)